# UITextField not Editable inside View ios storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitextfield

I am facing a problem with `UITextField` not clickable when placed in View component.
Steps to reproduce :

1. Place a View component in a rectangular shape.
2. Drag and drop `UITextfield` over View

I have set `userInteractionEnabled=true` property also. After building the project in Xcode, the input box is not editable.

Any solution for this.?

Comment: Did you set constraints ??

Comment: Provide more info about your problem. Storyboard screenshot or related code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the property "**Enabled**" under the **control** section is ticked.